# Creating a HotStream out of a Future via Spring Reactor

Tags: java, spring, reactive-programming, reactor

I wanted to prototype an example where I call a ServiceC using a value returned by ServiceA using Spring Reactor Stream API. So I wrote code like this

```
final ExecutorService executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(4, 4, 10, TimeUnit.MINUTES, new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());
        Streams.defer(executor.submit(new CallToRemoteServiceA()))
                .flatMap(s -> Streams.defer(executor.submit(new CallToRemoteServiceC(s))))
                    .consume(s -> System.out.println("End Result : " + s));
```

To simulate the latency involved in ServiceA and ServiceC the call() methods of CallToRemoteServiceA and CallToRemoteServiceC has Thread.sleep() methods. The problem is that when I comment out the Thread.sleep() method i.e. the service method calls have no latency which is not true in the real world the consume method gets called. If the Thread.sleep() methods are kept in place then the consume method doesn't get called. I understand that the Streams.defer() returns a cold stream and hence it probably only executes the consume method for items accepted after it's registration but then I was wondering how I could create a HotStream from a Future returned by the ExecutorService?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is because of a bug in the reactor.rx.stream.FutureStream.subscribe() method. In this line:

```
try {
        // Bug in the line below since unit is never null
        T result = unit == null ? future.get() : future.get(time, unit); 

        buffer.complete();

        onNext(result);
        onComplete();

} catch (Throwable e) {
        onError(e); <-- With default constructor this gets called if time == 0 and
                        future has as yet not returned
}
```

In this case when the default FutureStream(Future) constructor is called the unit is never null and hence the above code always calls future.get(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS) leading to an immediate timeout exception in the catch(Throwable) block. If you guys agree that this is a bug I can make a pull request with a fix for this issue??

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is to use `Streams.just`. You can optionally `.dispatchOn(Dispatcher)` if you want, but since you're already in the thread of the thread pool, you'll probably want to use the sync `Dispatcher`. Here's a quick test to illustrate:

```
@Test
public void streamsDotJust() throws InterruptedException {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    Streams
            .just(executor.submit(() -> "Hello World!"))
            .map(f -> {
                try {
                    return f.get();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException(e);
                }
            })
            .consume(System.out::println);

    Thread.sleep(100);
}
```